# How do I create (or remove) another FTP account for a client in Plesk?

Tags: ftp, plesk, reseller

I've currently got a reseller account with my hosting provider that I use for my clients (for their websites).

And I need to add/remove a FTP user, but for the life of me I can't work out how!

Am sure I've looked under every possible option, TWICE!

Based on the help document it appears to be v10.4 of Plesk if that helps.

Comment: Shouldn't the help docs have told you how to do this? (Serious question.) Unless you accessed a crippled copy or something. Here's the [docs at Parallels' site](http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP10/10.4/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-administrator-guide/plesk-control-panel-user-guide/)

Comment: http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP10/10.4/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-administrator-guide/plesk-control-panel-user-guide/65153.htm

There is no step 3 of "FTP Access" for me.

Even though for that client I've checked the option of allowing them unlimited FTP accounts.

Comment: I would recommend you contacting your hosting provider (from whom you purchased reseller account). My guess is that they restricted access to this feature if you can't see "FTP Access" button.

Answer (score 1):

Home > Subscriptions > (site) > Websites & Domains > FTP Access